# $V$ is open , then $V=\{x\in \mathbb R:f(x)>0\}$ for some continuous function $f$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Let $V$ be a non-empty open set of real numbers , then how to prove that there is a continuous function $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ such that $V=\{x\in \mathbb R:f(x)>0\}$

Comment: Take $f(x)$ to be the distance of $x$ to the complement of $V$.

Comment: @Etienne Would it also work to take the convolution of the characteristic function of $V$ with a bump function?

Comment: @MattN. I'm afraid your convolution will be positive at some points outside $V$.

Comment: @Etienne Too bad : ) Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 1):

Etienne's comment is a canonical construction of such a function: 
$$f(x) = \inf\{ |x-y| : y\in \mathbb R\setminus V\} $$
The key points are:

1. $f(x)=0 $ when $x\notin V$ (easy)
2. $f(x)>0$ when $x\in V$ (use the fact that $V$ contains a neighborhood of $x$ to give a lower bound for the set  $\{ |x-y| : y\in \mathbb R\setminus V\}$
3. $f(x) \le f(x')+  |x-x'|$ for all $x,x'\in \mathbb R$ (use the triangle inequality)
4. $|f(x) - f(x')| \le   |x-x'|$ (use item 3 twice)

---

As an aside: it is also possible to construct a smooth function $f$ with this property, see [Every closed subset $E\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is the zero point set of a smooth function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/791248/).