# Measure of $\partial\{g>0\}$ when $g$ is a $\mathcal C^1$ function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, derivatives, lebesgue-measure

Let $I\subset \mathbb R$ be a compact interval and $g:I\to\mathbb [0,\infty)$ a $\mathcal C^1$ function. Is it true that $$\lambda(\partial\{g>0\}) = 0,$$ where $\partial \{g>0\} := \overline{\{g>0\}}\setminus \mathrm{Int}(\{g>0\}) =  \overline{\{g>0\}}\setminus \{g>0\}$ and $\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue measure on $I$?

I think the above statement is true. However, I cannot prove it. Does anyone have a good idea?

Comment: ($\lambda$ is a more common symbol for the Lebesgue measure. Still good to say what you mean by it, of course.)

Comment: That's not the definition of $\partial$. But it's ok here since $\{g>0\}$ is open

Comment: @FShrike I agree with you, but since $\mathrm{Int}\{g>0\} =\{g>0\}$ and I am only interested in the boundary of $\{g>0\}$, I decied to write like this

Comment: A subset of $\Bbb R$ (or of $\Bbb R^n$ for that matter) is the zero set of some non-negative $C^\infty$ function if and only if it's closed. Therefore you may consider a dense open subset $\Omega$ of $I$ such that $\lambda(\Omega)\le \lambda(I)$, and $g$ such that $\{g>0\}=\Omega$ and $\{g=0\}=I\setminus\Omega$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio do you have a reference for this result?

Comment: @MatheusManzatto Which result? That every closed subset is the zero set of a non-negative $C^\infty$ function, or that there are dense open sets whose complement has positive measure?

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio the first, that every closed subset is the zero set of a non-negative $C^∞$ function. Nevermind, this is basically smooth Uryshon's lemma https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2891732/several-questions-on-smooth-urysohns-lemma

Comment: See [Eric Wofsey's answer to *Lebesgue measure of boundary of sets of roots*](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2848009/13130). Also -- [Can Cantor set be the zero set of a continuous function?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/24034/15780) AND [Infinitely differentiable function with given zero set?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/98577/13130) AND [Every closed subset ... is the zero point set of a smooth function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/791248/13130) AND [Finding a $\text C^\infty$ function which is zero just on a given closed set](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2411302/13130)