# Zero locus of a set of smooth functions. Smooth analogue of affine varieties.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, algebraic-geometry, notation, smooth-manifolds

The notion of an [affine variety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_variety) is one of the most fundamental concepts in algebraic geometry. It is just the zero locus of some finite set of polynomials $f_1,\dots,f_k$ from $\mathbb{F}[X_1,\dots,X_n]$.

In the class of smooth functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$ we can do the same. If $
 f_1,\dots,f_k$ are from $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then we can define $V(f_1,\dots, f_k)$ as the zero locus of $f_1,\dots,f_k$, i.e.,
$$V(f_1,\dots, f_k)=\lbrace x\in\mathbb{R}^n:f_i(x)=0, i=1\dots k\rbrace.$$

I am aware that $V(f_1,\dots, f_k)$ might not be a manifold, but still it is a very natural object to study.

> **Question.** Do objects like $V(f_1,\dots, f_k)$ have some name?
>
> ---

Edit. The point of the question is not to classify $V(f_1,\dots, f_k)$, but just to have a concrete name for such objects.

$V(f)$ are usually know as level sets (or level surfaces/hypersurfaces). Similarly $V(f_1,\dots,f_k)$ can be seen as $V(F)$ where $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^k$ is a smooth vector valued function. However, it looks like the notion of [level set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_set) applies only to real valued functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are called closed subsets :-) Indeed, any closed set $E \subset \Bbb R^n$ can be realized as such objects, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/791248/every-closed-subset-e-subseteq-mathbbrn-is-the-zero-point-set-of-a-smooth).

(In fact, you only need one function because $V(f_1, \dots, f_n) = V(f_1^2 + \dots + f_n^2)$ over the reals.)

Comment: Good to know that fact, but the intension of my question was different (even thou I haven't specified that). Usually $V(f)$ is called a level set (or level surface/hypersurface). Then we can compute gradient of $f$ and see if some point is regular or critical. I wonder if $V(f_1,\dots, f_k)$ have some name. PS. I will update a question a little bit in a moment.

Comment: @FallenApart I see, then I think my answer was not so appropriate. I'll delete it soon :)

Comment: Keep it! I found out something interesting from it and mayby others will do as well