# Boundary of the set of critical points

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, differential-geometry

Let $u\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and consider
$$ E = \partial\{x:Du(x)=0\}. $$
I am interested in understanding whether $\mu(E)=0$ or not, $\mu$ being the $d$-dimensional Lebesgue measure. What I could prove so far is that there exists a point $x\in E$ such that, for all neighborhoods $U\in U(x)$ we have
$$ \mu(E\cap \overline{U})>0. $$
Any idea on how to proceed with proving that $\mu(E)>0$, assumed that it is possible?

Answer (score 1):

The measure $\mu(E)$ may be positive or zero.  It is easy to give examples of the case $\mu(E) = 0$, so below is an example in $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ with $\mu(E) > 0$.

In light of this post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/791248/every-closed-subset-e-subseteq-mathbbrn-is-the-zero-point-set-of-a-smooth?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), it suffices to exhibit a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ whose boundary has positive measure.  In the spirit of what you pointed out in your question, the so-called [Fat Cantor Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set) is closed with empty interior (hence it is its own boundary).  Moreover, by computing a simple geometric sum one sees that it has positive measure.

Comment: It is possible to construct functions whose levels sets are a given closed set. However, in my case the function needs to be of the form $f(x) = |Du(x)|^2$ or something else such that $\partial f^{-1}(0)=E$. So maybe this constraint cancel the construction you are talking about.

Comment: @TommasoSeneci Let $f \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $f^{-1}(0)$ is given by the fat cantor set.  Such a function exists, as we agree.  Then just let $F$ be the antiderivative of this function.

Comment: you are right, thanks!