# How can a level set be convex?

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis

My course defines the level sets of a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ as

$$L_\alpha(f) = \{ x\in\mathbb{R}^n : f(x)=\alpha \}$$

For a problem, I need to find an $L_\alpha(f)$ that is a convex set. My issue is, how do I ever find a convex level set for a function that is not a straight line? For example the function $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ has a circular level set for all values of alpha.

Comment: What's the problem with a straight line? That's convex, isn't it?

Comment: For $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ the level set for $\alpha=0$ is the single point $(0,0)$. And a single point in $\mathbb R^n$ is convex.

Comment: Yes a straight line is convex, but I am looking for other convex level sets

Comment: @coffeemath for any other value of $\alpha$ however, the level set is non-convex right?

Comment: $f(x) = \max(1, x^2 + y^2)$ has a level set $L_1(f) = \{(x, y) \mid x^2 + y^2 \leq 1\}$, which is a disc.

Comment: @tealing123 Well when $\alpha<0$ the level set is empty, and so is vacuously convex. But for positive $\alpha$ the level set is not convex, as you say.

Comment: For an example in $\mathbb R^2$ where there are *no* level sets which are convex, consider $f(x,y)=y-x^2.$ Here the level set $f(x,y)=\alpha$ has as its graph $y=x^2+\alpha,$ which for any real $\alpha$ is a nondegenerate parabola.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a sufficiently smooth function $f$ "most" level sets can only be convex if they are hyperplanes or empty. Indeed, by Sard's theorem and implicit function theorem, for most values the level set is either empty or a closed submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ of dimension $n-1$, and by implicit function theorem near any point such a level set is a graph over its tangent space. Such a graph can be convex only if it's a graph of a linear function, so the whole thing has to be linear. So you can get convex non-linear level sets only at "non-generic values" (but of course you can get them; [any closed set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a level set of a smooth function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/791248/every-closed-subset-e-subseteq-mathbbrn-is-the-zero-point-set-of-a-smooth)).

Now, in convex analysis, what one usually looks at, is **sub**level sets, $S_a(f)=\{x| f(x)\leq a\}$; those are going to be convex as soon as $f$ is.

Comment: Note that the sublevel sets being convex is its own convexity property of $f$, called "subconvex". There are non-convex functions with convex sublevel sets, like $-e^{-x^2}$.

Comment: (Quasiconvex. The property is called quasiconvex, not subconvex.)